# How to remotely get DNS information?

Tags: windows, dns

I am trying to get DNS information on remote servers (via script or program I have yet to code).

On Windows boxes, I need to get DNS configuration. I have two ways of grabbing this information locally:

```
ipconfig /all
netsh interface ip show config
```

I could run these commands and pipe them into a find and out put it the way I want. The problem I have is running them remotely (I cannot use PSExec). netsh seems to have a remote tag, but the show config does not seem to work when running it remotely:

```
netsh -r IP_or_HostName interface ip show config

The following command was not found: interface ip show config.
```

It looks like all the command up to "config" works.

Any ideas of either how to use netsh to get the info I want or an alternative to find DNS information on a remtote machine?

tldr; How do I get DNS information from a remote machine (without using PSExec)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found/thought of something. One way to get it would be through WMI. You can access this by Powershell or VBS.

Comment: The answer would have been more helpful to others if it actually provided an example or a better solution other than it can be solved using PoweShell or VBS

Comment: You are welcome, but I was looking for another answer to you questions, and sadly yours did not help much.